# Trying to read and write a JSON file without using an external library or module in C++

Tags: c++, json

I want to read a JSON file without using an external library or module. When I'm trying to do that in the simple fashion (like reading/writing a .txt file), it doesn't read anything from the file.I want to read it line by line as a string, make some changes and replace the line. (Or just write into a new JSON file and use that).

What I want to do is to replace all instances of a char ("≠") with a simple hyphen("-")

What I have tried:

```
fs.open ("/Users/aditimalladi/CLionProjects/file/JSON_FILE");
string str;
while(getline(fs,str))
{       
    size_t index = 0;

while(true) {

    index = str.find("≠", index);
    if (index == std::string::npos) break;
    str.replace(index, 3, "-");
    index += 1;

}
```

How do I go about doing this? I know it is easier with jsoncpp and other similar modules. But I would like to do it without.

In the above code the entire file is being read and the character is not being replaced.

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use any libraries? Doing it without libraries is *really* hard.

Comment: C++98, C++03, C++11, C++14 or C++17?

Comment: I'm actually trying to convert another file type to JSON and then make changes. I am trying to minimize usage of more external libraries

Comment: All the libraries have it open source implemented. There are usually no much bloat code in those. More often there can be certain limitations, omissions or defects. So the answer of how to design reading and writing JSON format is available as source code of those libraries.

Comment: It is in c++11,

Comment: If you change your mind I recommend [This One](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

Comment: Converting another file *to* JSON is another matter altogether, and should not need any third-party libraries. As long as you can read the source file into suitable structures then writing those structures out to a JSON-formatted file should be trivial. However, that's is not what you ask about in your question. Reading and parsing a JSON file is *not* trivial.

Comment: ``Don't try to reinvent the wheels``. There are plenty of open source JSON parsers out there. Writing your own JSON parser won't be easy

Comment: Your question is missing some important information: what sort of changes are going to be needed? (As specific as possible.) The answer to that question determines how easy it will be to make the changes.

Comment: I just need to find a particular non-ascii char  ("≠") and replace all instances of it to a hyphen ("-").
Basically all I will need it for it to find and replace such strings.

Comment: Then I suggest you either edit this question to be about that issue instead, or delete this and post a new question. Specify what you want to do, and tell us what you have tried and how your attempts have failed. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend you learn about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you ask about a solution but wont tell us the problem.

Comment: @AditiM For something as simple as that, a basic `find` and `replace` should work. There almost certainly won't be need for a library, but the file encoding will need to be taken into account as well as whether is has any unicode byte order marks. Is the file in UTF8, UTF16 or UTF32?

Comment: The file is in UTF-8

Comment: Even for something like this will it be really tricky to do it without an external library?

Comment: Hrm, UTF8 complicates things a bit since C++ doesn't have any built in UTF8 handling. Also it seems that `'≠'` is U+2260 which means it takes 3 bytes to be encoded in UTF8, so to do it without a unicode library means you'll be looking for three consecutive bytes: `"\xE2\x89\xA0"` (i.e. replace the `"≠"` in your code with `"\xE2\x89\xA0"`, and double check those are the correct UTF8 bytes) . It's not ideal, but if it's really only happening once then it's probably cheaper than getting a full library in to solve a single small problem.

Comment: Actually, I was half wrong about C++ and UTF8. As of C++11 there's a `u8` prefixed string literal which makes matters easier.

Comment: Actually you don't care about the input file being JSON (it could be YAML or XML or HTML5 or LaTeX or some other kind of textual file, and you could have the same issue). You just know it is a textual file, and you want to replace `"≠"`  with `"-"`. You need to know that the input file is UTF-8 encoded, but today we have [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/). So your title is confusing. BTW you could simply run a `sed` or `ed` script to make the substitution.

Comment: I'm going to be another person to say this, but parsing JSON grammar, as limited as it is, is a lot of work (I've written my own parser, for fun). I would recommend using a header-only library like RapidJSON if you need speed, or nlohmann JSON if you need correctness. Both have been battle tested against numerous subtleties you wouldn't expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adjusting your code to (requires C++11):

```
fs.open ("/Users/aditimalladi/CLionProjects/file/JSON_FILE");
string str;
while(getline(fs,str))
{       
    size_t index = 0;

while(true) {

    index = str.find(u8"≠", index);
    if (index == std::string::npos) break;
    str.replace(index, 3, 1, '-');
    index += 1;

}
```

Or to keep your source code encoded in ascii, try:

```
fs.open ("/Users/aditimalladi/CLionProjects/file/JSON_FILE");
string str;
while(getline(fs,str))
{       
    size_t index = 0;

while(true) {

    index = str.find(u8"\u2260", index);
    if (index == std::string::npos) break;
    str.replace(index, 3, 1, '-');
    index += 1;

}
```

Or for pre C++11 or stdlibs without `u8`-prefixed literals:

```
fs.open ("/Users/aditimalladi/CLionProjects/file/JSON_FILE");
string str;
while(getline(fs,str))
{       
    size_t index = 0;

while(true) {

    index = str.find("\xE2\x89\xA0", index);
    if (index == std::string::npos) break;
    str.replace(index, 3, 1, '-');
    index += 1;

}
```

Comment: Hey, when I try to do this, the entire JSON in loaded into the string and it just breaks out from the loop in the next command.

Comment: @AditiM If the entire file is being loaded into the string, that suggests that there aren't any new lines in the file (which is completely legal for json). If the source text contains no newlines then things are going to get more complicated (especially if you can't read in the whole file at once).

Comment: So, if it's reading the entire file at once, it should still be able to find the instances of the char mentioned right?

Comment: @AditiM Yes. I've modified it slightly to make the code simpler. I tested another slightly modified version and it seems to work (although in my case the code can't find the file if the debugger is running for some reason, but it works when executed on its own).

Comment: It doesn't go on below the if condition, as it enters it and breaks out of the loop in the very first iteration. How can I solve that?

Comment: Are you sure the file is being opened properly? What does `fs.is_open()` return?

Comment: fs.is_open() returns 1

Comment: So well, I figured it never finds the "≠" char, which is why it is breaking out of the loop. The string str just has it like this : "�"

Comment: @AditiM  Are you sure the character is a ≠ (unicode U+2260)? Maybe it's something that looks similar but is at a different code point? (Perhaps it's a digraph.)

Comment: When I manually check the JSON file it shows up as a ≠ (U+2260) alright. So I don't think it could be a digraph right?

Comment: @AditiM When you say "shows up" do you mean in a text editor or in some system where you can view the json file as individual bytes? Also which version were you using? I just fixed a small mistake on the second one, as I just realised that `\u` and `\U` have different meanings.

Comment: Yes it works with \u. Thank you for the answer it works now! It was a UTF-8 encoding error